# Is it bad design to use logic gates for multiplexing?

Tags: pic, multiplexer

I have a PIC18F4550 which uses the same pin for UART RX and SPI data out.

Would it be bad design if I used a GP I/O pin and a logic gate to control the multiplexing of that pin?

[image]

When the IO1 pin is on, CTS (clear-to-send) will be turned off so the other module doesn't send any data.

When this is the case, IO2 pin will be asserted as well and therefore enabling data to flow to the SDI pin of another component. When SPI data is sent, IO2 and IO1 pin will again be de-asserted therefore stopping flow to the SDI pin and allowing DOUT to continue sending data to the RX pin.

IO1 and IO2 can be the same pin (this was quite stupid of me).

Would this be a good design or are there better ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to use logic gates for multiplexing in a microprocessor or micro-controller based system. Just make sure to use the logic family that is faster than your microcontroller clock speed. There are single discrete gates available in small SOT23 packages that may be suitable for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is okay, as long as the logic gate is faster than your micro as Chetan already mentioned. However, most SPI slaves have a Chip Select or CTS pin, with which you can set it to listening or not. You could use an inverter from IO1 to the Chip Select of the down-left component, so that one of the two always is listening. Since an inverter has only two pins, there go more in one package or the package is smaller, so that would save some space.